# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20003 Adaptive Server connection timed out [20003]

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, freetds, symfony-3.3

I'm trying to execute a store procedure on a SQL Server 2008.
After about 30 seconds it ends in

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20003 Adaptive Server connection timed
>   out [20003]

I've checked if on the SQL Server remote connections are allowed and they are with a timeout of 600 seconds (default).

This is my config.yml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default: ...
            mssql:
                driver_class: \Lsw\DoctrinePdoDblib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDODblib\Driver
                host:     mssql_freetds
                port:     "%stage_database_port%"
                dbname:   "%stage_database_name%"
                user:     "%stage_database_user%"
                password: "%stage_database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
                options:
                       timeout: 600 // I don't know if it's correct but it doesn't work even without this
```

And this is my code

```
$connection = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('mssql')
                ->getConnection();
$stmt = $connection->prepare("Exec SP_MyStoreProcedure ?, ?");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $sd->format("Y-m-d") /* This is a date */);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $ed->format("Y-m-d") /* This is a date */);
$stmt->execute();
```

**[EDIT]**

So, i've found that i should configure time out on freetds configuration because of LswDoctrinePdoDblib. I'v edited the /etc/freetds/freetds.conf file but it still ends up connection after 30 seconds

/etc/freetds/freetds.conf

```
#   $Id: freetds.conf,v 1.12 2007/12/25 06:02:36 jklowden Exp $
#
# This file is installed by FreeTDS if no file by the same
# name is found in the installation directory.
#
# For information about the layout of this file and its settings,
# see the freetds.conf manpage "man freetds.conf".

# Global settings are overridden by those in a database
# server specific section
[global]
        # TDS protocol version
;       tds version = 4.2

        # Whether to write a TDSDUMP file for diagnostic purposes
        # (setting this to /tmp is insecure on a multi-user system)
;       dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
;       debug flags = 0xffff

        # Command and connection timeouts
        timeout = 600
        connect timeout = 600

[mssql_freetds]
    host = 192.168.0.xx
    port = 1433
    timeout = 600
    tds version = 8.0
    client charset = UTF-8
    text size = 20971520
```

**[EDIT 2]**

Nothing worked for timeout except this:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default: ...
            mssql:
                driver_class: \Lsw\DoctrinePdoDblib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDODblib\Driver
                host:     mssql_freetds
                port:     "%stage_database_port%"
                dbname:   "%stage_database_name%"
                user:     "%stage_database_user%"
                password: "%stage_database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
                options:
                       2: 600 # 2 is the equivalent of \PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT
```

But the store procedure should end in 17seconds, it waited  10 minutes ending with the same result. I don't know why. It seems to be a FREETDS/SQL SERVER bug or something like that...

**[EDIT 3]**
Found that the problem was a "NOT IN" clause in the SQL of the stored procedure. I had to replace it with a LEFT JOIN combined with a IS NULL clause in WHERE statement. There's also a "IN" clause but it works. I don't know if it's a FREETDS or a LswDoctrinePdoDblib issue.

Comment: I don't know much about `symfony`, but I know in Python to bind parameters you need to pass actual Python date objects, not formatted strings. Don't use `8.0`, by the way, it is really `7.1`: http://www.freetds.org/userguide/tdshistory.htm This could be causing a problem with date fields: which are you using in SQL Server, `DATE`, `DATETIME` or `DATETIME2`? If using `DATE` or `DATETIME2` they didn't exist in TDS Version `7.1` (which `8.0` maps to - SQL Server 2000). It's a bit confusing, but I hope that made sense.

Comment: @FlipperPA it's not a problem of binded parameters, i've tryied with a simplier procedure passing the same "datetime" value in Y-m-d format (string) and it works. Maybe it's sometthing with the union or multiple insert statement in the original procedure. It's written by another developer, maybe i shold rewrite it in some way...

Comment: @FlipperPA after different attempts i've found that the problem is a NOT IN clause in the stored procedure.